# Intent.createChooser for ACTION_VIEW shows default browser only

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to show a app chooser dialog using Intent.createChooser, that will list all available web browsers in user's phone.
I'm using the code below:

```
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(category));
        // Create and start the chooser
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "Open with...");

        pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(helperMethodContext, 0, chooser, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Log.d("HelperMethods: ", "video chat url: " + category);
```

I am testing this on android 6. My phone has 3 browsers, default browser, chrome and firefox. When i run it and click on the link(the notification), app chooser dialog opens but only shows default browser. It doesn't show chrome or firefox.

[image: app chooser dialog after clicking on link in notification]

I have checked default apps settings in my phone and there is no default browser. When i click default browser it opens with an app chooser dialog showing all the browser apps i have installed on my phone.

Pls can someone tell me where am i going wrong.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel i don't want to open default browser when the link is clicked. I want to show the app chooser dialog with a list of all the installed browsers

Comment: this might be helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application

Comment: @JaydeepPatel I don't have default browser set in default apps settings. pls read the question completely.

Answer (score 0):

There is so important what type of uri do you have. Is it http, https or other scheme. In your case it's `Uri.parse(category)`. For example firefox can handle scheme like: `http`, `https`, `file`, `about`, `javascript`, `package`. And also data with mimeType: `text/html`, `text/plain` and `application/xhtml+xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
private static List<ResolveInfo> queryIntentActivities(PackageManager pm,Intent in) {
    ArrayList<ResolveInfo> queries=new ArrayList<>();
    {
        // get default queries
        List<ResolveInfo> i=pm.queryIntentActivities(in, 0);
        if(i!=null){
            queries.addAll(i);
        }
    }
    // check if package name already not set
    if(Utils.isEmpty(in.getPackage())){

        // search all installed apps for custom query
        for(ApplicationInfo ai:pm.getInstalledApplications(0)){

            // clone and change package name
            Intent intent=in.cloneFilter().setPackage(ai.packageName);

            // get queries of current package with intent
            List<ResolveInfo> i=pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

            // check if the app has queries for the intent
            if (i != null) {

                // add all queries to the list
                for(ResolveInfo ri:i){

                    // check for duplicate entries
                    if(!queries.contains(ri)){
                        queries.add(ri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return queries;
}
```

Make ur own UI to show the app list and get list like this:

```
List<ResolveInfo> queries = queryIntentActivities(getPackageManager(), new Intent()...);
```